# Fire CDI event AFTER bean creation via producer

Tags: events, cdi

I have a CDI producer method which creates an `UserBean`. The producer fires an `UserBeanEvent`. Other beans rely on that user bean and those beans may be used in the observer methods.

CDI again tries to create the user bean, the producer is invoked, the event is fired and so on - endless loop.

Is there any neat way to fire the event AFTER the producer completed and the bean was fully added to the bean store? I looked through the sources but I was not able to find anything.

I'm using WELD 2.3.5.final on WildFly 10.1

Comment: You are creating a cyclic dependency which is, in general, bad pattern. Try thinking your code through again, there may be other way around this but it's hard to say with little information the question provides. Can you give us a bigger picture of why you need to fire event at that point? The creation of beans is based on the activation of given scope/context so maybe you want to observe that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to detail several things, and one of the most important one is scope, and at what point is the bean needed?

Obviously if there is an observer method that listens to this bean event, and also needs a reference to this bean in the observer parameter, then you are definitely creating a cyclic dependency, which you cannot resolve, as the events in CDI are synchronous by default (And even if you use the `fireAsync`, there is no guarantee that by the time the event arrive, CDI has put the bean into proper context)

I would solve this problem by doing a method injection on an eargerly loaded bean such as ejbs `Singleton` or `@ApplicationScoped` with some kind of earger loading, and then fire the event from there.

Assuming that the bean is eargerly loaded:

```
public class EargerBean {

    @Inject
    private Event<BeanEvent> event;

    @Inject
    public void onInjected(Bean bean){
        BeanEvent beanEvent ...;
        event.fire(beanEvent);
    }

}
```